# How to Shrinkwrap bunch of planes to a Sphere while maintaining the planes' dimensions?

Tags: modifiers, objects, geometry, shrinkwrap, geometry-nodes

This is what I'm trying to achieve:
[image]
(notice that every plane object have the same dimension)

And this is what I came with so far:
[image]

The problem with this is that I need my planes to have four equal straight sides and four right angles. So is there any way to do this? *(maybe with geo nodes (which I completely have no experience with))*

Comment: Is a  manifold sphere grid with  exactly N a x a dimension squares possible?  Could look at [Quadrilateralized spherical cube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrilateralized_spherical_cube) which is an equal area mapping.  Related https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/3360/when-mapping-the-surface-of-a-sphere-with-tiles-how-might-you-deal-with-polar-d

Comment: Have you tried a particle system where you instance a plane on each face center ?

Comment: Maybe if you can show us some practical usage. Mathematically - it is not possible to cover sphere by squares (which shares edges) without some distortions. Only if quares are separated and you dont care about overlapping. That can be achieved only by triangles.

Comment: @vklidu yes the squares must be separated and overlapping is okay. This is for Minecraft, it's the only way to make sphere in it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this with Duplifaces, by parenting a plane to your sphere.

[image]

Subdivide a cube enough times and add a *Cast* modifier to make it perfectly spherical.

Add a plane and scale it appropriately, then parent it to the sphere with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>.

[image]

Under the *Object* tab of the *Properties Window* activate the *Faces* option in the *Instancing* panel.

If you want them as separate independent objects select your sphere then go to *Object > Apply > Make Instances Real*