# Perfectly even quad sphere

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, vertices, faces, subdivision-surface

I want to make a perfectly even sphere out of quads in blender. but everyone keeps just making cubes and adding subdivision surface to them, which is not a perfect sphere.

Do you guys know how to make it so that all quad faces of a sphere are the exact same size hence making a perfectly even mesh and therefore sphere?

[image]

I am planning on making a planet map and i need all chunks to be the same size! I want a perfectly even, quad sphere mesh to do this.

Comment: The long and the short of it is it cannot be done - A sphere cannot be completely comprised of even sized quads. Your best bet is the subdivided cube. If you want the subdivided cube to me more "sphere-like" in shape (not topology), add a _cast modifier_ set to _sphere_ (default), and increase the _factor_ to 1.

Comment: You need to add a cast modifier to make it a perfect sphere, just as @ChristopherBennett said. But if by "perfect" you mean that all the quad faces are the same size, I'm sorry to disappoint you because it's impossible. If you want a sphere for a planet, you can use a UV Sphere which doesn't have a very good topology but it's perfect for equirectangular maps like planet maps.

Comment: This is what the sphere would look like if it was made of perfect squares https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/227269/how-to-shrinkwrap-bunch-of-planes-to-a-sphere-while-maintaining-the-planes-dime

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't write in all caps, it is the online equivalent of shouting, is [harder to read](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Readability) and may be [considered rude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Computing). You can use the [edit] button below to change you text into regular case.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett All quads the same _shape_ is not possible, but same _size_ (i.e. surface area) should be.

Answer (score 2):

The best you can get is a spherified cube if you insist on quads...

```
for f in faces:
  origin = get_origin(f)
  right = get_right_dir(f)
  up = get_up_dir(f)
  for j in div_count:
    for i in div_count:
      p = origin + 2.0 * (right * i + up * j) / div_count
      p2 = p * p
      rx = sqrt(1.0 - 0.5 * (p2.y + p2.z) + p2.y*p2.z/3.0)
      ry = sqrt(1.0 - 0.5 * (p2.z + p2.x) + p2.z*p2.x/3.0)
      rz = sqrt(1.0 - 0.5 * (p2.x + p2.y) + p2.x*p2.y/3.0)
      return (rx, ry, rz)
```

[image: Four methods Sphere Mesh]

source: https://medium.com/@oscarsc/four-ways-to-create-a-mesh-for-a-sphere-d7956b825db4