# Is it possible to make a sphere that made of equilateral squares?

Tags: modeling

It is possible to make a sphere out of equilateral triangles, but can you make a sphere out of squares of equal size?

Comment: Short answer is no - this is the reason there are so many different "projections" of the map of the earth - you cannot map a spherical area to a rectangular (or square) area without distortion of some sort.

Comment: Thanks, i am sure the link will help

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/227269/how-to-shrinkwrap-bunch-of-planes-to-a-sphere-while-maintaining-the-planes-dime